# Segment raster image with pixel values and population size

Tags: r, raster

I usually use ENVI to do this process, however I am trying to move towards keeping everything within R to script more of my raster processing.

Within ENVI, the tool I use is called "Segmentation Image." The parameters include pixel thresholds, a population minimum, and number of neighbors considered. It works by first finding all pixels that meet the defined thresholds then grouping those pixels together if they collectively meet the population size.

Is there a way to pull this off within R? It seems like a relatively simple analysis, but I can't seem to find a function that will do it.

Thanks you!

Comment: Can you provide some example data and possible output?

Comment: Example: an NDVI raster approximately 200x200m in size of a forested area. I want to set a minimum NDVI threshold (0.5) and a minimum group population (25 pixels). The output would show all areas where there are 25+ adjacent pixels that have NDVI of at least 0.5.

Comment: Please provide some example data generated with R code. Not a description. The expectation here is that you have a reproducible example of the problem, with some code that you have developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
vi <- raster(ncols=20, nrows=20, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1)
set.seed(101)
values(vi) <- runif(ncell(vi)) * .9
```

Reclassify

```
m <- c(-1, 0.5, 0, 
        0.5, 1, 1)
r <- reclassify(vi, m)
```

Find patches (here only Rook-case patches)

```
rc <- clump(r, directions=4) 
#plot(rc)
```

Get patch size and select those larger than 10

```
f <- freq(rc)
ff <- f[f[,2]>10, 1]
ff <- ff[!is.na(ff)]
```

Select the patches larger than 10

```
msk <- subs(rc, data.frame(ff, 1))
```

And use that to select the grid cells in the original raster

```
z <- mask(vi, msk)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. Sorry for the lack of example, I wasn't sure how to generate an example raster, but you showed an example of how to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Robert's example above, this is the code that I ended up with to accomplish my task.

```
# set parameters
min_val <- 0.5
min_pop <- 9
neighbors <- 8

# reclassify all cells
# values between -1 and min_val become 0
# values between min_val and 1 become 1
r <- ndvi
r[r > min_val] <- 1
r[r <= min_val] <- 0

# clump together cells
rc <- clump(r, directions = neighbors, gaps = TRUE)

# get patch size and select those larger than min_pop
f <- freq(rc)
ff <- f[f[,2] >= min_pop, 1]
ff <- ff[!is.na(ff)]

# select those larger than 10
msk <- subs(rc, data.frame(ff, 1))

# mask original NDVI raster
z <- mask(ndvi, msk)

# make result binary
z[z > 0] <- 1
z[is.na(z)] <- 0}
```

Comment: seems that you do not need `mask`. You can do `z <- reclassify(msk, cbind(NA, 0))`